# JuliaCall & MixedModels Extract the Fixed-effects parameters into a R data frame

Tags: r, julia, mixed-models

I am using JuliaCall R package to run GLMM with Julia on R following this tutorial:https://rpubs.com/dmbates/377897

I have successfully performed my model but I don’t know how to store the 'Fixed-effects parameters' into an R data frame in order to work with it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation of `MixedModels`: http://dmbates.github.io/MixedModels.jl/stable/constructors.html#Fixed-effects-parameter-estimates-1. The fixed effect estimate can be extracted using Julia function `fixef`, and the return value is not a `DataFrame` but a vector in Julia, and `JuliaCall` should be able to convert it to an R vector automatically. So you can try things like:

`julia_eval("fixef(gm1)")` ## if the result is stored in Julia as gm1, or
`julia_call("fixef", gm1)` ## if the result is stored in R as gm1